# Access connectionString using Iconfiguration in repository

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm working with DOTNET6  and i want to use the connection string from Iconfiguration
in my repository.

I added it on program.cs :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
```

but unable to use it outside in one of the repository files.

Here is the constructor of the repository, but i know it is not the right way to use it:

```
public class CartsTransactionRepositoryDapper :ICartsTransactionRepositoryDapper
    {
        private IDbConnection db;
        private IConfiguration configuration;
        
        public CartsTransactionRepositoryDapper(IConfiguration configuration) 
        {
            this.db = new SqlConnection(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        }
```

How can i get the connectionString here?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @asher, how is your appsettings.json like? From you code, it should get the connection string.

Comment: Like you mentioned in the code, you can directly access it via IConfiguration. It is available as builder.Configuration. You dont need any extra code to access IConfiguration.  It will injected automatically

Answer (score 1):

add `configuration = configuration` in the constructor before connection string declaration.